# Docx4J.toPDF error:Property ID "XXX" (found on "fo:inline") previously used; ID values must be unique within a document

Tags: docx4j

An exception occurred while trying to convert word toPDF using the method [Docx4J.toPDF].
I suspect it's because I used the method [XmlUtils.deepCopy] to copy the table in word.
Because I have a list in the project, I copy the table according to the number of lists

Docx4j USES the tag ${name} to replace the content, has successfully copied the table and generated word, but made a mistake in converting the word to PDF.
Other words without table copy can be normally converted into PDF

```java
    public static void replaceTcContentList(Body body, Tbl tbl, List<Map> valueMapList, WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage) throws Exception {
        // copy table
        for (int i=1; i<valueMapList.size(); i++) {
            Tbl copyTbl = XmlUtils.deepCopy(tbl);
            body.getContent().add(copyTbl);
            body.getContent().add(new P());
        }
        // Retrieve the entire table
        MyTblFinder tblFinder = new MyTblFinder();
        new TraversalUtil(body, tblFinder);
        for(int i=1; i<tblFinder.getTbls().size(); i++){
            Tbl childTbl = tblFinder.getTbls().get(i);
            Map<String, String> valueMap = valueMapList.get(i-1);
            replaceTcContent(childTbl, valueMap, "${QRCode}", 65, 65, wordMLPackage);
        }
    }
```

```java
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:106)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:734)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:749)
    at com.kf.utils.word.Doc4jUtils2.plProcessCard(Doc4jUtils2.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at 
    at 
Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception writing Document to OutputStream: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: 
Property ID "XXXX" (found on "fo:inline") previously used; ID values must be unique within a document! (See position 7:7519)
    at org.docx4j.utils.XmlSerializerUtil.serialize(XmlSerializerUtil.java:56)
    at org.docx4j.utils.XmlSerializerUtil.serialize(XmlSerializerUtil.java:18)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:253)
    at
```

I know the ID of the field XXX in the copied table is not unique, I want to modify it, but I don't know how to modify it.